# Error numérico o de valor: el búfer de cadena de caracteres es demasiado pequeño Oracle

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql

necesito que me ayuden a encontrarle la soluciòn a un error que me aparece al ejecutarlo.

Declare dos variables:
--message de tipo varchar2(35)
--date_written de tipo date

Asìgnele los siguientes valores:

--message:='este es mi primer programa de pl/sql'

--date_written:=fecha de hoy

Grabe los valores en la columna apropiada de la tabla temp

Tengo el siguiente bloque PL/SQL:

DECLARE

```
  mensaje VARCHAR2(35) := 'este es mi primer programa de pl/sql'; 

  date_written DATE := TO_DATE(SYSDATE, 'YYYY-MM-DD');
```

BEGIN

```
  INSERT INTO temp (num_store, shar_store, date_store)
             VALUES(1, mensaje, date_written) ;
  COMMIT;
```

END;

El error que me genera es:

ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 2

Ayuda por favor.

Answer (score 3):

La cadena "este es mi primer programa de pl/sql" tiene 36 caracteres y lo estás intentado meter en una variable de 35 caracteres "VARCHAR2(35)"

Saludos!